# Won't "Answer your own question" just encourage people to game the system?

Tags: support, asking, self-answer

It's *bad enough* when folks zerg rush the site with sockpuppets during contests or major launches. But now we're directly encouraging folks to [rep-whore](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/etiquette-of-immediately-answering-ones-own-question)?!!

[image: the selfanswer checkbox on Gaming]

What *possible* good can come of this?!!!

Comment: Has there actually been an issue with zerg-rushing sock puppets?

Comment: AFAIK, a few people have tried sockpuppetting the contests; it didn't end well for them.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/etiquette-of-immediately-answering-ones-own-question/4680#comment13376_4680

Comment: Good questions and answers are independent of who posts them.

Comment: @NickT Completely true, but pretending there's a limit on the number of good questions that can be asked is kind of silly. If I really wanted to exploit the contest I could find a dozen great questions in an hour.

Answer (score 20):

I know, right? Folks are gonna dump all their [tips and information](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8210/how-do-i-run-starcraft-brood-war-on-windows-7-without-problems) in a [convenient format](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36433/besides-perks-what-other-permanent-abilities-can-i-get) that [appeals to other readers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66055/how-far-is-a-yard-on-screen) and make off with all of our precious EXP!

Oh, wait... That's the idea.

This already happens. In fact, it's been *encouraged in [the first FAQ section](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)* from **day one.** It could - and maybe *should* - happen a lot more. Some of us tend to answer our own questions, without ever even asking them... And we could really be helping folks out if, upon struggling with something for a while before solving it, we spent the time to write up what we learned.

So the new UI strives to make that an obvious choice, without inadvertently [misleading readers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8210/how-do-i-run-starcraft-brood-war-on-windows-7-without-problems#comment10784_8210) into thinking they need to jump in and help you with your question while you struggle to get that answer out.

And if you see someone post something useless in a blatant attempt to get rep for nothing... Down-vote, close, delete. Or publicly shame them by posting a better answer. Be creative...

#### See also: [What is this “answer your own question” jazz?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz/132887#132887) on Meta SO.

Comment: WAIT!  You answered this question as you posted it!  I'm going to report you to the moderators and/or the employees of the network!!!one!!!

Comment: Attempting to rep-whore in meta...I think your plan is flawed.

Comment: This is meta meta...

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/917/)

Answer (score 1):

Just used it for the first time. This is Nifty. I like it. Though if it'd been around when I asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46369/how-do-i-get-a-magenta-lightsaber-crystal/46378#46378) for the purpose of self answering, I wouldn't have been able to [game the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119177/gaming-the-system-for-populist-badges) for a Populist badge.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a good thing. I recently asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67061/what-is-the-optimal-marine-stutter-step-frequency-and-timing) as I was interested how to get better in Starcraft.

An answer pointed me in the right direction, so I knew what to look for and where I could find it. I took the time to read through some of the new sources I found this way and combined everything into an answer.

I could have asked for further details or waited a few days, but this way I am satisfied  with the provided pointers and I can share my results.

Before I had to edit my question adding a "Solution" section. Sure this works but this is not the intention of this site, is it?

I think it is good that you have to wait to accept your own answer and you do not get any points for that.

Comment: Just to be clear, you've *always* been able (and encouraged) to answer your own question. What's new is the button allowing you to do so *at the same time that you ask it* -  as in, before anyone else gets the chance to answer you.