# Will there continue to be 48-hour accept timer for self answered questions?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, accepted-answer

With the recent change that you can [ask and answer at the same time](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4681/15643), I'm curious if that will effect the 48-hour delay in accepting your own answer as correct. Will it be eliminated? Shortened? Increased? Goes nowhere and I'm off my rocker for even thinking it might?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, eliminating the delay would not be the best as it would encourage users to not accept newer answers, but maybe shortening it would be good.

It gives the opportunity for users to post their answers that they know are correct, gives them a shorter window for having to remember to come back and accept, and yet does not discourage others from posting potentially more informative answers that serve to answer the question better.

Right now, with the 48 hour window, I often don't remember for a few days that I need to mark it, so if a user does not notice that it is self-answered, they may not realize it is the correct answer.

Comment: Be honest, you only wanted to test it didn't you? :)

Comment: @JuanManuel Haha, actually, didn't have to. Asked a couple of questions on SO that never got answered a day or so ago and answered one of them myself ;)