# Can I answer my own question?

Tags: support, self-answer

I wanted to ask a question so that I can answer it. I want to do this to help out people with the same question or issue, saving them the trouble of writing a question.
Is this an acceptable thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! As long as you make sure both the question and answer would stand on their own (without relying on the other), it's totally acceptable, even encouraged.

See: [Etiquette of *immediately* answering one's own question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/etiquette-of-immediately-answering-ones-own-question)

Comment: You also need _some_ reputation in order to answer your questions within 8 hours of posting it. I think the bar is 10 reps.